# Type inference issue after class inheritance in typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose there is a class `Base` where the `print` method expects the parameter to be `IBaseContext` merged with the generic type `T`.

```
interface IBaseContext {
  a: number
}

class Base<T> {
  public print(context: IBaseContext & T) {

  }
}
```

use the class `Test` to inherit the class `Base`.

```
interface IMoreContext {
  b: string
}

class Test extends Base<IMoreContext> {
  public print(context) {

  }
}
```

expected overridden `print` method parameter inferred to be `IBaseContext & IMoreContext`, but got `any`.

I've tried changing the class `Base` to an abstract class, changing the two interfaces to two types, or [DeepMergeTwoTypes](https://github.com/Svehla/TS_DeepMerge), it doesn't seem to work.

How to make it infer correctly, is there something I misunderstood? thank you

Comment: You don't need generics or interfaces to see this, [here's a simple repro](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbC4BOxAdgC4AUwA9rQgB40Bc0ENlVA5gEoUGbNAC+GSegyhIMACoIe0NjQRUAJjHgQkaTNnxFSFavSYt2wg6OzTxQA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this seems to be a limitation of typescript.. from [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373)

```
export enum SortDir
{
    Asc,
    Desc,
    Flip
}

export interface ISortInfo
{
    getvalue(x: QuerySummary): any; //change to number|string in TypeScript 1.4
    order: SortDir;
    ordercalc?: number;
}

class SortByQueryId implements ISortInfo
{
    getvalue = x => x.QueryId;
    order = SortDir.Flip;
}
```

> when I type "x." I expect to see the properties of QuerySummary but I do not. VS still thinks the type is 'any'

The conclusion is:

> Unfortunately, we couldn't come up with a solution that was consistent and backward-compatible. See #6118 for details. I'm closing this for now.

Comment: Please quote enough of the issue that if it disappeared, the answer would still make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm not familiar yet

Comment: Don't quote the SO question (that's here already!), quote the parts of the page you've linked to (the TypeScript issue) that answer the question.